# How can a .jar folder be portable?

Tags: java, jar, javafx-2, executable-jar

I am developing a JavaFX application. When building my project, I noticed that my jar folder can't be opened when I changed its place. I checked my jar folder and i found that my `lib` folder is missing  .

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  A JAR is a file, not a folder. If you change it's place you need to change your class path. If you haven't built you JAR correctly you shouldn't expect it to have the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your JAR file needs the libs in the classpath to be able to run. Whenever you move the jar you need to move the libs folder as well.

If you want to avoid that there are tools to package the libs into one jar but generally that approach is to be avoided as it makes it much harder to do builds, incremental updates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the definition of portability here - when people talk about a jar file being portable, they usually mean that it can run on multiple architectures without change (since it uses bytecode.) What they don't usually mean is that you can just rip it out from its location, dump it somewhere else and expect it to magically find all the resources it needs!

Usually your jar file just contains your class files, perhaps with some miscellaneous resources in there as well. While everything that your application depends on *can* be located in the one jar file, it's much more common to have these in the same directory outside of that file since it makes replacing individual components and updating the software much easier.

If you absolutely must have your application in one portable jar file, then have a look at [One-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), which does just that.

Answer (score -1):

Use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to include all dependencies in your project. Easier to manage.